# Testing a simple API call function in React using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've a component using an API call to retrieve an array on render. There seems to be an infinite number of ways to test this, but every attempt I've made hasn't worked. I have the following attempt/errors (simplified for brevity):

`/PunkApi.tsx:`

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchApi()
            .then((parsed) => {
                setApiData(parsed);
            })
    }, []);
```

`fetchApi()` is imported from here:

`/punkApi.ts:`

```js
export function fetchApi(): Promise<Beer[]> {
    return fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers')
        .then((response) => response.json()) as Promise<Beer[]>;
}
```

I'm attempting to test by following a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klDnAGZHHqI):

`/PunkApi.spec.tsx:`

```js
import * as APIService from './punkApi';

jest.mock('./punkApi');

test.only('renders table rows', async () => {
    APIService.fetchApi().mockResolvedValueOnce(exampleBeers);
    const mock = jest.spyOn(APIService, 'fetchApi').mockResolvedValue(exampleBeers); // LINTER ERROR: Property 'mockResolvedValueOnce' does not exist on type 'Promise<Beer[]>'.ts(2339)
    render(<PunkApi />);
    expect(APIService.fetchApi()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    await waitFor(() => null);
});
```

Console output:

```
 FAIL  src/components/PunkApi/PunkApi.spec.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

      42 |      useEffect(() => {
    > 43 |              fetchApi()
      44 |                      .then((parsed) => {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, having looked at more than a dozen tutorials that no longer work (presumably due to `react-testing-library` updates), I found that the easiest guide was in the ([testing-library.com/docs... documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro)) all along.

Essentially include this before the test:

```js
import {setupServer} from 'msw/node'

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json([{myArrayResponse: data}]))
  }),
)


beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())
```

And that will mock the 'https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers' endpoint, ensuring that the `[{myArrayResponse: data}]` is returned to the fetch request.